# enabling textboxes for user input with a single selection from a static combo box list selection in visual basic wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net

This is a Visual Basic **WPF** question. 
I have a list of static items in a Combo-Box.
I need to enable two text-boxes for user input in order to make an additional calculation from the input for only two of the items in the Combo-Box drop down list and only two of them.  Selection of 8 items in which either of 2 of 8 will enable the user to input into the two additional text-boxes ONLY when that particular item in the list is selected.  So this has to be done in XAML.  I want to calculate the cost of additional energy used in the form of water when a water based appliance is selected requiring the two additional input text box fields.

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="Appliances"  SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged ="Appliances_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="243,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True">
        <system1:String>TV</system1:String>
        <system1:String>Air Conditioner</system1:String>
        <system1:String>Heater</system1:String>
        <system1:String>Fan</system1:String>
        <system1:String>Refrigerator</system1:String>
        <system1:String>Oven</system1:String>
        <system1:String>LaundryWasher</system1:String>
        <system1:String>Dishwasher</system1:String>
    </ComboBox>




Public Sub Appliances_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

    Dim theSelectedItem As String = Appliances.SelectedItem

    Select Case Appliances.SelectedItem

        Case "TV"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "Air Conditioner"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "Heater"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "Fan"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "Refrigerator"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "Oven"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "LaundryWasher"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case "Dishwasher"
            LabelTwo.Content = "Appliance: " + theSelectedItem
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an Appliance.")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly do you want ?

Comment: by the way...the WPF code u posted is unnecessary ...

Comment: Why limit this only to XAML? Why not consider other ways of achieving your outcomes?

Comment: Why do u think it can only be achieved using XAML ?? where a single line vb code can get the job done?

Comment: When laundry washer or dishwasher is selected I need two textboxes to be enabled for additional numeric input only when either one is selected in the dropdown of the combo box item list.

Comment: The code is a requirement because its what is asked to be done.  A combo box with 5 text box fields for input where 3 are used part of the time and then 5 are used with certain item selections form within the item list of the combo box.  So with one line of code how do you select the changed indexes when properties are not available in WPF like they are in winforms?

Comment: So this is homework and you figured you'd keep that part secret?

Comment: Based on the lack of online information for the missing windows forms properties in WPF I am already rewriting a new program in regular windows forms.  I had it all working minus the one aspect.  IS there something wrong with asking a question that an answer cannot be found for?  I am looking for the specific difference in change in XAML.